# VBA Array Transpose Column Missing

Tags: vba, excel

I am manually transposing a large array from a recordset (.transpose did not work) but the first column is missing. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong

```
   Dim FinalArr As Variant

    ReDim FinalArr(1 To UBound(ArrRs1, 2), 1 To UBound(ArrRs1, 1))
    For i = 1 To UBound(ArrRs1, 2)
        For j = 1 To UBound(ArrRs1, 1)
            FinalArr(i, j) = ArrRs1(j, i)
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: Is the lower bound of `ArrRs1` zero?  If so, you should use `0 To` instead of `1 To` (in declaration and loops).

Comment: @YowE3K Well look at that, I didn't know arrays could start on 0. Thanks!

Comment: Use `LBound` if you are not sure if an array is 0-based or 1-based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array had a lower bound of 0.

```
Dim PasteArray As Variant

ReDim PasteArray(1 To UBound(ArrRs1, 2), 0 To UBound(ArrRs1, 1))
For i = 1 To UBound(ArrRs1, 2)
    For j = 0 To UBound(ArrRs1, 1)
        PasteArray(i, j) = ArrRs1(j, i)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Did you check that the second dimension wasn't zero-based too?